# Excel: Not getting a button-down image on a command button

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got an Excel workbook with a couple of command buttons (form controls) on it. The command buttons are connected to 'on_click' macros, which work as expected. But it's a bit difficult to see what's going on, because the buttons don't change to a 'button down' image when they are clicked.

Is this a known problem? What could be going on?

Comment: Did you use the standard form controls, the ActiveX controls, or another COM add-in command button? Are you still in design mode?

Comment: As spikey_richie said, please ensure the design mode is off. Besides, is the **TakeFocusOnClick** True? If yes, does the issue occur with other workbooks? Maybe you could go to `C:\Users\<user account>\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0`, delete the temporary files with .exd extension.